# Vue Js List Rendering Change Array With Splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, array-splice

```
    let vm = new Vue({
        el:"#app",
        data:{
            users:[
                {
                    name:"Murad"
                },
                {
                    name:"Maxi"
                },

            ]
        }
    })
```

vm.users[1] = {name:"John"};

this is not work but

vm.users.splice(0,1,{name:"John"})

and after 
vm.users[1] = {name:"John"};

this is work  Why after splice change array with index work?

Answer (score 2):

Vue doesn't trigger a change for a modified array value, but does for splice

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods

Vue will automatically trigger for the following array functions:

- push()
- pop()
- shift()
- unshift()
- splice()
- sort()
- reverse()

Comment: I know vue doesn't trigger a change for a modified array value but your  change array with splice after you can change array with index see my example

Comment: @MuradSofiyev JavaScript is single threaded. Doing a splice will queue up an update. You then change the value, then the update happens.